# Pass value of kCFCalendarUnitWeekday

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification, nsdatecomponents

I want to set an alarm on a particular day. I don't understand how to set the value of `kCFCalendarUnitWeekday`. Here is my code:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
if (localNotif == nil)
    return;
localNotif.fireDate = selected;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.repeatCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

if (isSun) {
    [components setWeekday:1];

    [localNotif setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];
}

if (isMon) {
    [components setWeekday:2];
    [localNotif  setRepeatInterval:(NSInteger)components];  
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is some code to get you in the right direction:

```
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    // this will set the weekday to sunday
[components setWeekday:1];
    // this is a new date on sunday
NSDate * newDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];
```

You still have to find out whether the newDate is in the past, so it won't fire.

---

You actually have your code ready:

```
// ... init code ...

// *** this the important date ***
localNotif.fireDate = dateOnASunday;
localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotif.repeatCalendar = NSWeekCalendarUnit;

... // add body etc. ...

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
[localNotif release];
```

Create a method around this snippet and pass the date with a parameter so you can reuse it. You only have to put in a date which should be the first fire date and it'll repeat every week. You just have to pass in a date on a Sunday or Wednesday.

You set a repeat interval like this:

```
// repeats notification on a weekly basis
localNotif.repeatCalendar = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
```

The repeatCalender property is of type [NSCalendarUnit](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001451-SW2) which is an enum.

Comment: Thanks ans the question but if i want to set the notification on every Monday, Wednesday then what can i  do and i am using NSWeekCalendarUnit.

Comment: I think that you have to set two notification for that: Each starting date respectively on a monday and on a wednesday, then choose weekely.

Comment: how i can do this ? plz give answer by coding or modify above example? i want to set notification on every monday & wednesday or friday etc. Thank you.

Comment: ya got point but how i calculate the up coming days like sunday or monady. means how i calculate the dateOnASunday ?

Comment: how get value of dateOnASunday? & how to get value up comping days like sunday , monday etc?